# @RequestMapping параметры. Как сделать Request в котором параметры не обязательны?

Tags: java, spring

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Object get(@RequestParam(value = "ID", required = false) int id) {
        return id;
    }
```

Как сделать так чтобы можно было обращаться / без параметров. В данный момент можно только /?id=213.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Object get(@RequestParam(required = false, defailtValue = "0") int id) {
    return id;
}
```

или так

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Object get(@RequestParam Optional<Integer> id) {
    return id;
}
```